# MySqlDump in LiquiBase

Tags: liquibase

I add this changeset in `dn.changelog.xml` (XML file regarding liquibase):

```
<changeset id="1" author="dheeraj">
<executeCommand executable="mysqldump"/>
</changeset>
```

When I run update command, I get this error:

```
mysqldump returned an error code of 1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return code "`1`" seems to indicate a usage problem. I guess you will have to add further parameters to `mysqldump` to make it work. 
You can add parameters to `executeCommand` like this:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="<you>">
    <executeCommand executable="mysqldump">
        <arg value="-u root"/>
        <arg value="-p [root_password]>"/>
        <arg value="[database_name]"/>
    </executeCommand>
</changeSet>
```

This is untested code! It is just an example to get you started!

Comment: The best way on stackoverlow to say thanks is by accepting and/or upvoting my answer... :-)